# Checking for undefined constants

Tags: php, constants, undefined

I've seen a lot of people using

`defined('XXX') or define('XXX', 'XXX');`

instead of

```
if(!defined('XXX')){
  define('XXX', 'XXX');
}
```

Does the first code do exactly the same thing? Why do people use it?

Answer (score 2):

The feature is called [short circuit evaluation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) and it's common to many languages. Boolean expressions are evaluated from left to right and evaluation stops when there's already a result. In this case, if the constant is defined the expression is `TRUE` no matter the other term, so define() does not run.

Answer (score 1):

They do exactly the same thing.  The first is just shorter to write.  Similar to using

```
mysql_connect(...) or die('some error');
```

The right side of the logical `OR` is evaluated only if the left side is `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

Does the exact same thing. Basically its (TRUE CONDITION) or FALSE ALTERNATIVE

Answer (score 0):

It does exactly the same, relying on the fact that logical OR requires evaluation of the second operand if the first evaluates to FALSE.

I wouldn't use this method too broadly, as it tends to "short-circuit" conditionals (i.e. `TRUE or f();` - f() will never be called)

Comment: huh? logical operators are short-circuiting.

Comment: Corrected even as you were writing the comment. As soon as I hit submit I felt I forgot something or not forgotten something :)

Comment: hmm that's not much better. the whole idea of using `or` is that the second predicate is never going to be evaluated if the first is true.

Comment: Actually, that's what I said: the second gets evaluated IF (and only if) the first one evaluates to false. So in the OP's case, the desired effect is achieved: either your constant is defined, or it will be defined now. Short circuiting screws you up if you expect to get to second operand, but never do.

Comment: I just referred to the second part. if you want to evaluate both of them why on earth would you use `or`?

Comment: you wouldn't. And actually, while some things may work, you still shouldn't do them. Code readability is one good reasons to avoid conditionals as statements. Another is that some languages/compilers may start evaluating right-to-left, completely screwing up your intended logic.

Comment: *can* you name one language and compiler which does evaluates `and` and `or` from right?